# Creating a set of new columns based on other sets of columns and based on the IF THEN condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a third set of columns based on two other sets of columns and based on the additional IF THEN condition.  It works, but I am not sure how to introduce a condition that would limit division to only those rows where both list_A and list_B are higher than zero.  In other words, I want to execute computation only if the numbers in both sets A and B are higher than zero because that's the condition that makes the division meaningful. And, if either list A or B is zero then I would like list C be zero. I tried NumPy where approach, but I am getting error.  Thank you. Here is example

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='M')
dft = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4),index=dates, columns=['var_A1', 
'var_A2', 'var_B1', 'var_B2'])
list_A=['var_A1', 'var_A2']
list_B=['var_B1', 'var_B2']
list_C=['var_C1', 'var_C2']
C=pd.DataFrame(data=dft[list_A].values/dft[list_B].values,columns=list_C,
index=dft.index) 
dft=pd.concat([dft,C],axis=1)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? you can try: `dft['var_C1'] = np.where(dft['var_C1'] < 0, 0, dft['var_C1'])`

Answer (score 0):

c = pd.DataFrame(data=np.where(((dft[list_A].values>0) & (dft[list_B].values>0)), dft[list_A].values/dft[list_B].values, 0),columns=list_C,index=dft.index) 
dft=pd.concat([dft,c],axis=1)